# MOUSE_MOVE event throw frequency in flash and html5

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

When I move mouse over `Sprite` and draw curve according to recieved coordinates. I've noticed that `MOUSE_MOVE` event is thrown not so frequently. Here's the question: what is exaxt frequency that `MOUSE_MOVE` is thrown. And the same question cincerning html5: how often `MOUSE_MOVE` is thrown there.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may be tied to the frame rate, try different frame rates and see how often it fires, from memory its been pretty damn reliable over the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MOUSE_MOVE` is fired at a reasonable time laps but faster than `RENDER` thus generating image lag. You can fix this by updating the scene when the event is catch:

```
private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Triggers a RENDER event
    event.updateAfterEvent();

    // Do whatever you want
    // ...
}
```